# Inspect DOM while pausing script execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dom-inspector

I have code that changes the DOM while executing, and I want to inspect the DOM during the code execution. The problem is, if I pause script execution (i.e. by using a breakpoint), Chrome prevents me from inspecting the DOM.

Is there a way to do it?

(specifically, I want to inspect SVG elements during animation, for example)

Comment: what do you mean by "chrome prevents me from inspecting the dom"?

Comment: I can't right click on an element to inspect it, and moving the mouse through the elements in the Element tab does not highlight the element on the page

Comment: I've experienced this sometimes too and always wondered how to get around it in Chrome?  The odd thing is that it only happens sometimes.  On many breakpoints, you can inspect the DOM, but some you cannot.

Comment: Can you provide an example? It sounds like a Chrome bug.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel - set a breakpoint in the first line of this event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jgyfLnfn/.  Then try to right click to inspect anywhere in the document pane after it hits the breakpoint.  You can't.

Comment: @jfriend00 you can't right-click, but inspector icon (magnifying glass) works just fine for me.